# Writing a function to find ehe volume under$ |f(x,y)|$ over an area

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, homework

I need to write a function to find the volume under a surface $|f(x, y)|$ and over an certain area. The output of the function is going to be the volume and a plot.

For example:

Given $|f(x,y)|=|3+x^2 - 2y|$ and the area specified by $0<x\leq1 \land -x\leq y<x$

the output should be

[image]

#### Edit

I tried the formulas for integration and plotting, but my code failed. The result that I got was:

```
try[solid_, x1_ && y1_] :=
  Module[{volume1, plot1},
    volume1 = Integrate[Abs[solid], x1, y1];
    plot1 = Plot3D[Abs[solid], x1, y1];
    Print[volume1];
    Print[plot1]]

try[x^2 + y^2 + 2, -1 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1]
```

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in -1<=x<=1.
> Plot3D::pllim: Range specification -1<=x<=1 is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}.

```
(*
  Integrate[Abs[2 + x^2 + y^2], -1 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1]  
  Plot3D[Abs[2 + x^2 + y^2], -1 <= x <=1, 0 <= y <= 1]
*)
```

Here is how it looks in my notebook.

[image]

What should I change to make the function work?

Comment: This can be easily found in documentation.

Comment: @yarchik excuse me, but what documentation are you talking about? and where can i find it? thank you.

Comment: @loki right here for `Integrate` https://wolfram.com/xid/0mrb9e-k30pof

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

```
Integrate[
  Abs[x^2 - 2 y + 3]
, {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[-x <= y < x, {{x, 0, 1}, y}]
 ]
```

> 7/2

```
Plot3D[
  Abs[x^2 - 2 y + 3]
, {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[-x <= y < x, {{x, 0, 1}, y}]
, Filling -> Axis
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. I must use the Module function to complete it.

Comment: @loki how about you lookup docs for `Module` and just wrap this solution with it?